# Project Euler #24 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to solve the problems from **Project Euler** using Haskell, but I got sucked at [#24](https://projecteuler.net/problem=24)

I'm trying to use factorials to solve problem but just can't work for the last three digits, here is my code:

```
import Data.List
fact n = product [n, n-1 .. 1]
recur :: Int -> Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
recur x y arr
    | y > 1     = arr !! d : recur r (y-1) (delete (arr !! d) arr)
    | otherwise = arr
    where d = x `div` fact y
          r = x `mod` fact y

main::IO()
main = print(recur 1000000 9 [0..9])
```

(I know it is now not really "functional")
I managed to get result `[2,7,8,3,9,1,4,5,0,6]`, while the right answer I accidently figured out by hand is **2783915460**.

I just want to know why this algorithm doesn't work for the last three digits. Thanks.

Comment: `(delete (arr !! d) arr)` is not a proper way to delete an element from list.

Comment: Have you tested with smaller cases that your function generates all the permutations in lexicographical order?

Comment: @bipll in general, yes, but here there are no duplicates in the list of choices, so it's OK.

Comment: @WillNess Sure, as long as your notion of "OK" implies 1. taking an element of a list (O(d)), 2. deleting that element (d comparisons, plus list reconstruction). Is it really a reasonable way to remove an element whose index you _already know_?

Comment: @bipll "OK" in the sense of overall correctness. (you can't see it, but I've upvoted your comment, too). :) @ OP, the proper way to do it is with `splitAt`.

Comment: Side note: you want to use `divMod` (resp. `quotRem`) when you need both `div` and `mod` (`quot` and `rem`) on the same numbers. That's (usually) one division operation over two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unadulterated `divMod` is wrong for this algorithm. You need

```
dvm x facty | r == 0    = (d-1, facty)
            | otherwise = (d, r)
                  where
                  (d, r) = divMod x facty
```

instead:

```
recur x y arr
.......
.......
    where (d, r) = x `dvm` fact y
```

We cannot have *zero combinations to do* left. Zero means none.

Also the pattern guard condition should be changed to `y > 0`. Only when the length of the remaining choices list is 1 (at which point `y` is 0) there's no more choices to be made and we just use the last available digit left.

Comment: Can also be written `dvm x facty = let (d, r) = divMod (x-1) facty in (d, r+1)`

Comment: Not really.  In this form, `r+1` is fed back as `x` in the next iteration, where we `divMod` with `x-1`, so we can see that the `+1` and `-1` cancel each other out, so plain `divMod` could have been used if we just started with `999999` instead of `1000000` because we should have started counting from `0` instead of `1`.